# SSD upgrade from M.2 SATA to NVME for Acer Aspire VX5-591G?

Tags: laptop, ssd, sata, acer-aspire, nvme

My laptop Acer Aspire VX5-591G-72DL came with following storage options -

- 128GB M.2 SATA SSD and
- 1TB HDD

Is it possible to ***upgrade*** the 128GB SATA SSD to a 1TB NVME SSD, preferably a *Samsung EVO 970 Plus* ?

**Useful links** -

- [My laptop's M.2 SSD Slot image](https://i.imgur.com/0mL9pVF.jpeg)
- [Acer VX5-591G-72DL Data Sheet](https://www.acer.com/datasheets/2017/4876/VX5-591G/NH.GM2SI.004.html)
- [Intel HM175 Chipset Data Sheet](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/98085/mobile-intel-hm175-chipset/specifications.html)

Comment: There are various sites to check SSD comparability, such as Kingston and Crucial; perhaps Samsung offers a similar guide. However, Super User does not provide hardware recommendations. You might try https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Overview-of-M-2-SSDs-586/ at least compare pins on your ssd with saumsung photos and size of both

Comment: https://pcguide101.com/storage/how-to-tell-if-my-m-2-slot-is-nvme-or-sata/

Comment: You already have the answer https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/671748/nvme-ssd-support-for-acer-aspire-vx5-591g